# Add new Foursquare Loyalty Special

Tags: foursquare

I'd like to please ask about the correct parameter to pass when creating a new loyalty special when selecting from these 2 options (visible in website):

At each venue separately
Across all venues together

It is not reflected in api https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/specials/add on how to pass one of the options.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to specify granularity level for loyalty specials via the API. I've asked internally for this to be added to the API endpoint and will get back to you when that happens!